# What is the right way to compare two JSON Strings using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

What is the right way to compare two JSON Strings using GSON?

```
boolean match = false;
String json2 = "some json string";
String json1 = "another json string";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement t2 = parser.parse(json2);
JsonElement t1 = parser.parse(json1);
match = t2.equals(t1); // compare two json strings
if (match) {
    // do something
}
```

Does my above code looks right for two JSON comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the sample code you supplied? If you use 2 equal JSON strings but rearrange the order of the keys, you'll find your answer...

Here is sample code :

```
String json1="  { \"name\" :\"ABC\",\"city\":\"XYZ\"}";
String json2="  { \"city\":\"XYZ\", \"name\" :\"ABC\"}";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement t2 = parser.parse(json2);
JsonElement t1 = parser.parse(json1); // returns true
```

Comment: @user2809564 Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Just wanted to double check whether my understanding is right or not.

Comment: Some dude edited my post to add in what I mentioned. I personally am against doing this because it takes away from the questioner's learning experience. It's generally a good idea to try it out yourself (note that you didn't even put sample json into your snippet, just dummy text).


That said, you may want to test out json structures with more depth before committing to it, or at least to the complexity of whatever you're using it for.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean the compare really string-to-string or content-to-content?

if you are comparing string-to-string, you should use

```
int difference=aStr.compareTo(bStr);
```

if your are comparing content-to-content, you should use GSON to convert the JSON into a POJO and implement the equalsTo method in that POJO.

e.g.:

```
public class City implements Comparable<City>{
    public String name;
    public int population;

    public int compareTo(City b){
        return name.compareTo(b.name)+population-b.population;
    }
}

Gson g=new Gson();
City a=g.fromJson(jsonA, City.class);
City b=g.fromJson(jsonB, City.class);

int difference=a.compareTo(b);
```